# AS3 sort.(Array.DESCENDING) issue

Tags: actionscript-3

here is the issue

```
var enemy_preference_ordered:Array = new Array();
enemy_preference_ordered = [60, 20, 12, 8];
enemy_preference_ordered.sort(Array.DESCENDING);

trace(enemy_preference_ordered) // output 8,60,20,12
```

I want it to be in descending order so the output should be 60,20,12,8, what step did I miss?

Answer (score 3):

If you adjust argument of `sort` function, you should get desired result.

```
enemy_preference_ordered.sort(Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC);
```

Comment: what does | do in the sort, does it mean descending & numeric?

Comment: @AdamEdney These are flags, in order for them both to be active you need to place "bitwise OR" `|` operator between them. `&` will just set flags to zero, because the result of "bitwise AND" operator on two separate flags is zero, thus your array will be sorted ascending.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.NUMERIC`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#NUMERIC) too , like:

```
enemy_preference_ordered.sort(Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC);
```